# How to debug in Clion using Cmake if project needs libraries

Tags: debugging, cmake, clion, termcap

I'm new in C. My code uses termcap library. And I'm trying to debug my code using Clion through Cmake Application. But it can't be compiled because functions that i use from a library are undefined. What should i add to CMakeLists.txt to debug my project?
My CMakeLists.txt now:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(minishell C)
 
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
 
add_executable(minishell main.c)
```

When i compile using clang i just do this:

```
clang main.c -ltermcap
```

and it works.
Can't understand what to do. Please help.

Comment: So the question is how to **link** with a library in CMake? It so, then linking is performed with `target_link_libraries` command. This is written in almost any tutorial for CMake...

Comment: The actual error-messages aren't shown.  Also, it's unlikely that the proper library is `-ltermcap` since almost all systems use a termcap interface over terminfo, e.g., `-lncurses`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.